# Good idea to use Google Sites for static content and custom PHP for dynamic

Tags: security, authentication, iframe, google-sites

We have a site based upon Google Sites. Now we would like to create a login area (HTTPS) with a mixture of dynamic and static content. Is it a good idea to utilize Google Sites and use iFrames for the dynamic parts of the content?

The reason why I like Google Sites, is that it is so easy to change content and immediately see what it will look like.

Comment: I would suggest to use AJAX, or PHP custom file includes with CURL/File get contents code.

Comment: @Trouble So you basically mean that I should turn my idea upside down (or inside out) and create a PHP page with elements from Google Sites? This sounds like an interesting alternative. But how should I insert the content code into the site. I don't think I could have the Google Sites content inside iFrames?

Comment: You can call your page with CURL request and create so called "wrapper" around your own content, AJAX would work to load dynamic content on your Google Site.

Answer (score 2):

Iframes are not SEO friendly nor are they accessible. They should be avoided if at all possible. You can accomplish you goal using other technologies that also allow you to see immediate results (PHP, etc).

Comment: I am very curious about what other technologies I could use. SEO is not a concern on these pages as they require login.